# Variance of a sample mean with sample size $< n$

Tags: probability-distributions, self-learning

Let's say I have a sample mean $\bar X$ computed on $s$ random variables among $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ where $n>s$:

\begin{align}
\bar X = \frac{1}{s}\sum_{i=1}^{s}X_i
\end{align}

For simplicity, let's assume the $X_i$ are i.i.d. $\text{Bernoulli}(p)$.
My question is: what would be variance of $\bar X$?

By using the definition of variance, I have

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(\bar X) = \operatorname{Var} \left(\frac{1}{s}\sum_{i=1}^{s}X_i \right) = \frac{1}{s^2}\sum_{i=1}^{s}\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = \frac{1}{s^2}\sum_{i=1}^{s}p(1-p) = \frac{p(1-p)}{s}
\end{align}

But this doesn't feel right to me since it ignores how many random variables there are, i.e. $n$.

Comment: But you *are* right.  If the variables $X_{s+1},\dots,X_n$ aren't used, they are, in some sense, *not there*, so you shouldn't feel bad.

Comment: I found a very similar question (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304226/bernoulli-estimator-bias) and the answer there confuses me. Who is right?

Comment: You calculated the variance correctly.  $\overline X$ is an unbiased estimate of $p$.  In a limiting situation, where $s\to\infty$, the variance tends to 0 and $\overline X$ is *consistent*.  It is true that there are better estimates of $p$, such as the average of all available $X_i$: they have smaller variances.  If $\lim s/n<1$ the average based on $s$ samples is called *inefficient*, meaning its asymptotic variance is asymptotically much worse than the best.

Comment: I see. But if the variance is $\frac{p(1-p)}{s}$ and the bias is 0, to prove consistency it would be necessary that $\frac{p(1-p)}{s} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. But the variance is not a function of $n$. That's what I don't understand! @kimchilover

Comment: Earlier in the sentence that bothers you, I said "where $s\to\infty$".  You are right: without this the estimate is not consistent.  If it uses fewer than all the observations the variance is not as small as it might be, and so on and so on.

Comment: Thank you! I have found peace.